# Trigger to Sum Multiple Rows After Insert on same Table

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a database with one table on Oracle.

My problem is the following:

- I would like to create a trigger to sum some values in my table and put the total value on the different fields.

For example, my table, `(RKAP_RENCANA)` has 13 columns.

```
ID  DETAIL  JAN  FEB  MAR  APR  MAY JUNE TOTAL
------------------------------------------------
1    TEXT    10   10   10   10   10   10   60
2    TEXT    20   40   10   10   20   10   110
```

So finally I would like to sum values `(JAN - JUNE) values in RKAP_RENCANA` and put the total value on `TOTAL Field`

So far, I've tried in several ways but it seems it didn't work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TEST_TOTAL 
  ON dbo.RKAP_RENCANA
  FOR INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 UPDATE M
   SET TOTAL = T.JAN + T.FEB + T.MARCH + T.APR + T.MAY + T.JUNE
   FROM dbo.RKAP_RENCANA AS M
   INNER JOIN inserted AS T
     ON M.ID = T.ID;
END
GO
```

Are there any other ways to solve my problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Oracle?

Comment: SQL Oracle Sir...

Comment: . . I ask because `dbo` is often associated with SQL Server -- and the rest of the syntax is SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle 11g and above, you can use a generated column instead:

```
alter table RKAP_RENCANA add total number
     generated always as (JAN + FEB + MAR + APR + MAY + JUN)
```

Comment: Sir @Gordon Linoff, can you help me one more time, how can I still calculate if there is a NULL value between JAN - JUN?

Comment: You can use `COALESCE()` to turn the `NULL` values into `0`s.